# Adding Photos To Blogger Blog Automatically Adds Them To Google Plus Photos: How To Disable

Tags: google-plus, blogger

When I add a picture to my Blogger Blog, the same picture gets added to my Google Plus photo gallery. I then delete them in Google Photos because excess clutter bothers me. It's not that the Blogger photos are sourced there, because after I've removed them from Photos, they're still on the Blog. Where can I go to set it so that pictures added to my Blogger blog are never automatically added to my Plus photo gallery in the first place? Hopefully, this is the right Stack Exchange to get an answer to this question.

Note: I've never done the profile switch thing in Blogger settings to switch to a Google+ profile on Blogger.

Comment: Deleting photos in Google+ is a great way to also delete them from Blogger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm very surprised that the photos are still in your blog after you've removed them from your Google+ gallery - are you sure that it's not just a cached version that you're seeing.

What Google have told us is that there is one set of photos, and that they can be accessed from either PWA or Google+ Photos, and of course they can be loaded (but not managed in any other way)  with Blogger.   So what you're seeing is not clutter at all, just a 2nd interface to the same thing.